# dismiss something in a dynamic list

Tags: list, flutter

The code below is fine I have just an issue with the return Dismissible(key: Key(**list**).

The Key(list) says 'the argument type list... can't be assigned to the parameter type.'

I mean the list isn't defined because its dynamice and gets information from the user.

Someone who has a solution?

```
  TextEditingController tc;
  List<String> list = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tc = TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      body:ListView.builder(
        itemCount:list.length,
      itemBuilder:(context,index){
       return Dismissible(key: Key(list),
        onDismissed: (direction) {
          setState(()
          {
            list.removeAt(index);
          }); Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('$list dismissed')));
          Container(color: Colors.red);

        },

       child: ListTile(
        title:Text(list[index],
                  style: TextStyle(color:Colors.black)),


                  ));
  }));}

  void showPopup() {
    tc.text = '';
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (con) => AlertDialog(
                title: Text('Add new Asset'),
                content: TextField(
                    controller: tc,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      labelText: 'Asset',
                    )),
                actions: [
                 MaterialButton(
            child: Text('ADD'),
            onPressed: () {
                        if (tc.text.trim().isNotEmpty) addToList();
                        Navigator.of(con).pop();
                      })
                ]));
  }

  void addToList() {
    setState(() {
      list.add(tc.text.trim());
    });
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The **Key** takes a **String** as a parameter, not a **List**. A good way to achieve this is using **UniqueKey**

For Example

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {

  var myList = List.generate(100, (index) => index);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: myList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index){
            return Dismissible(
              key: UniqueKey(),
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text("Hey $index"),
              ),
              onDismissed: (direction){
                myList.removeAt(index);
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can also achieve this by using the index as the key
Like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {

  var myList = List.generate(100, (index) => index);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: myList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index){
            return Dismissible(
              key: Key("$index"),
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text("Hey $index"),
              ),
              onDismissed: (direction){
                myList.removeAt(index);
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I hope this helps you.